# Continuous deformation of soap films

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, mg.metric-geometry, calculus-of-variations, geometric-measure-theory, geometric-analysis

Let $S$ be a soap film bounded by an unknotted wireframe cycle (in $R^3$). Why is it the case that as we deform the wireframe in $R^3$, $S$ deforms continuously?

Comment: and what about the phenomenon of continuous deformations of soap operas?

Answer (score 14):

You are asking whether a least area surface depends continuously on its boundary curve, or in mathematical terms: whether for every curve $\gamma$ there exists a least area surface $S$ with $\partial S=\gamma$ such that for any neighborhood of $S$ in the space of surfaces there exists a neighborhood of $\gamma$ in the space of curves such that for any curve $\gamma^\prime$ in that neighborhood one will find a least area surface $S^\prime$ with $\partial S^\prime=\gamma^\prime$ in the first neighborhood.

This is however not always the case, see

Beeson: [Non-continuous dependence of surfaces of least area on the boundary curve.](https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.pjm/1102812419) Pacific J. Math. 70 (1977), no. 1, 11–17.